# AJAX $.get() Not Returning any Response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to integrate ajax for the first time in my wordpress theme I am doing. This is my first attempt and I researched on the syntax and how it works. So far, my script is executed properly but there's no response.

The `$.get` Request

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.get('Ajax-nao.php',{cat:12,ponum:5,panum:1},function(data) {
 alert('data sent'+ data);
 });
});
```

The Ajax-nao.php

```
 $categoryid = $_GET['cat'];
 $postnum = $_GET['ponum'];
 $pagenum = $_GET['panum'];

 $args = array (
        'cat' => $categoryid,
        'posts_per_page' => $postnum,
        'paged' => $pagenum
);
$q = new WP_Query($args);
while( $q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
    $post_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
    $wrapper = '<h2 class="column-titles">' . get_the_title() . '</h2>' . '<p>' . $post_excerpt . '</p>';
    echo $wrapper;
endwhile;
```

home.php <-- Where the results will be displayed.

```
    <div id="social-bar">
    <div id="other-posts" class="just-float-left">

    <div id="other-Posts-container">

    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me pin-point my error?

Comment: is the success function being called?

Comment: Does `Ajax-nao.php` display anything? Have you tried looking into firebug and see the request being made and the server response?

Comment: Have you tried calling the PHP from a POST direct from the form (not using AJAX)? It might help you troubleshoot the issue by getting echo'd responses from the script.

Comment: Does Ajax-nao.php work correctly when called directly?

Comment: Check in the Firebug console - you will see all requests and their responses. If there's no request in there, the call is not being made.

Comment: I did try it first in form and it works. @user75164

Comment: @ManuelvanRijn Yes. It's in the header.php of wordpress.

Comment: I found the problem. It seems that it's trying to find my php in the root directory and not in my theme. Thanks for those who suggested firebug. Now I have another question.

Answer (score 1):

`WP_Query($args)` returns empty set.

At the end of your PHP script change it from:

```
            echo $wrapper;
endwhile
```

to:

```
    echo $wrapper;
    exit();
endwhile
echo "No results found!";
```

you will gain assurance if there is any data found.

Comment: Agreed, it's generally good to echo out some failure state to guarantee that the ajax call is even hitting the the correct script on the backend.

Comment: Still nothing. It also didn't return the "no results found!" echo.

Comment: Then it might be because it's not calling your script correctly. The path to your PHP script is relative to the script or markup calling it, so if it's not in the same folder as your jquery, you need to modify the path.